# Uploading App Preview to App Store Connect: Preview Too Long

Tags: macos, preview

Trying to upload an App Preview to App Store Connect and am getting the message: "One or more of your app previews are too long".

This is for the Mac App Store.  The preview was created in iMovie and is 4:48 minutes long.  It is 207.4 MB in size.

In the requirements, I don't see any restriction on the length of the preview, just the size.  It is all within the 500 MB.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App previews can only be (up to) 30 seconds long.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/)

> App previews demonstrate the features, functionality, and user
>   interface of your app using footage captured on device. You can have
>   up to three app previews for each language your app supports, and each
>   preview can **be up to 30 seconds long**. The following tips can help you
>   create compelling previews that spark interest and drive downloads of
>   your app.

Create three single videos of 30 seconds each. Focus on the most important features of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  They should probably add this to the "Requirements" page you get when clicking the "?" next to the place you upload app previews.